# Header image is not aligning properly to top of container div on iPhone (6s) emails

Tags: html, iphone, email

[Notice that the image isn't flushed to the top, instead it has a gap. It looks fine on all emails, but on iPhones I'm getting this to happen. How can I fix this on iPhone emails?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVN71.png)

Here is the inlined code for the container divs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

</head>

<body style="padding:0;">

<div class="email-background" style="background: #eee;padding: 10px;">

<div class="email-container" style="max-width: 600px;background: white;background-image: url(body_textur_bkg.jpg);font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 5px; display:block; padding: 0px;">

    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
<img src="thankyou_header_link.jpg" style=" max-width:100%;vertical-align: top;"></a>

<h1 class="name" style="margin: 40px;font-size: 25px;text-align: left;color: #666;line-height: 1.5;">
[CANDIDATE_NAME],.....
```

Not sure if you need the rest of the code, but I can post if needed.

Comment: Which image are you is not aligning? The rounded edge one?

Comment: Yes, the image titled thankyou_header_link.jpg

Comment: The image not aligning is the feature image in blue. I want it to align to the top and not have the white space small white space.

Comment: Have you tried removing the padding from the div above it?

Comment: I did, but that wasn't the fix.

Comment: I just fixed it. It was adding margin: 0px to the style of the image. Thanks for the help though, I guess you have to add as much as possible to the style sheet in order for iPhones to display them properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code to see if it fixes it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

</head>

<body style="padding:0;">

<div class="email-background" style="background: #eee;padding:0px 10px;">

<div class="email-container" style="max-width: 600px;background: white;background-image: url(body_textur_bkg.jpg);font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0 auto; overflow: hidden; border-radius: 5px; display:block; padding: 0px;">

    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">
<img src="thankyou_header_link.jpg" style=" max-width:100%;vertical-align: top;border:0px; display:block;"></a>

<h1 class="name" style="margin: 40px;font-size: 25px;text-align: left;color: #666;line-height: 1.5;">
[CANDIDATE_NAME],.....
```

Let me know if it fixes it.

Cheers